# PrismaClientInitializationError during nextjs build - why does nextjs need to access the database at all?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

While trying to build my nextjs application (`npm run build`), it seems that the DB is being requested during build time on certain routes where I expect to dynamically query data. Since the DB is not up nor live in my build environment, this leads to `PrismaClientInitializationError`. I'm curious what I've configured incorrectly here, as I assume nextjs is thinking this is a page that needs to render content statically at build time, when I assumed dynamic would be a default.

Page

```
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await prisma.my_data.findMany()
  return (
    <div>
        { /* render html elements using data */ }
    </div>
  )
}
```

the error:

```
67.05 Can't reach database server at `postgresdb`:`5432`
67.05
67.05 Please make sure your database server is running at `postgresdb`:`5432`.
67.05     at wn.handleRequestError (/app/.next/server/chunks/438.js:6947:32)
67.05     at wn.handleAndLogRequestError (/app/.next/server/chunks/438.js:6908:18)
67.05     at wn.request (/app/.next/server/chunks/438.js:6890:18)
67.05     at async l1 (/app/.next/server/chunks/438.js:7438:26)
67.05     at async getProductionsCrawlerStatus (/app/.next/server/chunks/605.js:27:12)
67.05     at async Page (/app/.next/server/app/(main)/partyfinder/status/page.js:555:25) {
67.05   clientVersion: '5.3.1',
67.05   errorCode: undefined
67.05 }
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ezik @nathan I guess this is what Next.js SRC expected behavior, you can force pages to be dynamic to avoid database fetches, eg. `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';`. Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#server-rendering-strategies

Answer (score 1):

Adding this fixed it for me:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

Otherwise, I was getting this error duing `next build`:

```bash
#18 30.38 Error occurred prerendering page "/api/get". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
#18 30.38
#18 30.38 SqliteError: no such table: user
#18 30.38     at Database.prepare (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/better-sqlite3@9.4.1/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/methods/wrappers.js:5:21)
#18 30.38     at e2.prepareQuery (/app/.next/server/chunks/383.js:13:17435)
#18 30.38     at e2.prepareOneTimeQuery (/app/.next/server/chunks/383.js:13:16369)
#18 30.38     at e$.prepare (/app/.next/server/chunks/383.js:13:5379)
#18 30.38     at e$.all (/app/.next/server/chunks/383.js:13:5601)
#18 30.38     at e$.execute (/app/.next/server/chunks/383.js:13:5512)
#18 30.38     at p (/app/.next/server/app/api/get/route.js:1:549)
#18 30.38     at /app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:42490
```

For context, I was trying to build a `Dockerfile` with [Next.js, Drizzle, & SQLite where it was constantly failing.](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/)