# Why Next.js build trying to connect to database?

Tags: next.js

I have server page in Next.js 14 using App Router that will fetch data from database,

Here is where the database connectoin pool is created, at `lib/db.js`

```js
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

import * as schema from "@/schema";

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  ...
});

export const db = drizzle(pool, { mode: "default", schema });
```

then the above is imported in server component page like this,

```js
// create database connection
import { db } from "@/lib/db";

const Dashboard = async () => {
  const result = await db.query.documents.findFirst();
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
};
```

this implementation requires a running database server. This makes sense when npm run dev or in the production runtime.

What is not clear to me is that npm run build is also trying to connect to the database. The build will fail when the database server is not running.

What is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here, at [will nextjs always require database access at build time on statically generated pages? Or have I screwed up something with my config](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/16yh4xs/will_nextjs_always_require_database_access_at/).

Answer (score 1):

I went with a [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78015026/6141587) of doing this on every route that calls a database:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

**Update:** [I found an even simpler solution](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/issues/1155) of using only one connection by adding a config in Next.js.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        // recommended to solve https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/issues/1155
        workerThreads: false,
        cpus: 1,
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, the build process pre-renders pages by default. This means it generates the HTML for each page at build time. If you have a server-side function or data fetching logic directly in your component (like in your Dashboard component), Next.js will try to execute it during the build process.

As your Dashboard component is trying to fetch data from the database during rendering, and this rendering happens at build time, Next.js attempts to connect to the database during the build. If the database server is not running, this will result in a failure.

To avoid this issue, you should move your data fetching logic to `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. These functions are specifically designed for data fetching in Next.js and are only called at runtime for `getServerSideProps`, or at build time (and optionally at runtime) for `getStaticProps`.

Here's how you could refactor your Dashboard component using `getServerSideProps`:

```
import { db } from "@/lib/db";

const Dashboard = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const result = await db.query.documents.findFirst();

  return { props: { data: result } };
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Hmmm ... the `getServerSideProps` is using page router? I'm not familiar with page router but how does that different from app routers?